# Site automatic redirect

Tags: javascript, http, redirect

I want to redirect my site with javascript. The intended behavior is that the user waits for a certain period of time then gets taken to a new page.

Comment: Looks like Sindarin.

Comment: SO Is English only. Also, before you post in English, make sure your post contains _all_ the relevant details and information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var shant="redirect_adress" 
function forPage()
{
location.href=shant
}
setTimeout ("forPage()", time); 
</script>
```

time 1000 ms = 1 s

Adress http://

Comment: Should probably use `setTimeout(forPage, süre);` - passing a string to `setTimeout()` can have weird effects.

Comment: @Pointy I don't think it will have weird effects

Comment: It's good to avoid because the code in the string is evaluated in the **global** context, not the local context. If the function name referenced in the string is a local function, then it won't work.

Comment: The above friend wanted to redirect the only one page